# pivot_wider a single row

Tags: r, tidyr

This morning was running through my usual routine; coffee, NYT, and R based problems/learning.  Have been working on a blog post, and utilizing the `tidycensus` package, and developed an interesting problem.

How to pivot_wider a single row from a table?
or
How to create proportions based on the condition of a single row?

I am trying to create a proportion of white and black population data based on Total population. The initial table looks like this...

```
Ohio_population_acs5 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(Total = sum(estimate))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  ID                            Total
  <chr>                       <dbl>
1 Black or African American 1336133
2 Total                     8204988
3 White                     6283529
```

Using this table, my initial thought was to `pivot_wider()` the table, `then pivot_longer()` for a result that looks like this...

```
Ohio_population_acs5 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(Total = sum(estimate)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = ID, values_from = Total) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(`Black or African American`,`White`), names_to = "ID", values_to = "value")

# A tibble: 2 x 3
    Total ID                          value
    <dbl> <chr>                       <dbl>
1 8204988 Black or African American 1336133
2 8204988 White                     6283529
```

Then create a proportion ratio between the value column and the Total...

```
Ohio_population_acs5 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(Total = sum(estimate)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = ID, values_from = Total) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(`Black or African American`,`White`), names_to = "ID", values_to = "value") %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Prop_pop = value/Total)

# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   ID [2]
    Total ID                          value Prop_pop
    <dbl> <chr>                       <dbl>    <dbl>
1 8204988 Black or African American 1336133    0.163
2 8204988 White                     6283529    0.766
```

However, it would be far more convenient to select the **row** to `pivot_wider()` rather than the full column, then fill the values.  Maybe there is an easier way to go about this process, but seems like there might be a function or process to combine the `pivot_wider`- `pivot_longer` into a single operation, especially to extract a single row value.

Hope this is an easier question than others.
Thank you for the help with this, and looking forward to the responses.  Please let me know if any clarification is needed (or reproducible example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get to that output without any pivoting

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  rename_at('Total', ~'value') %>% 
  transmute(Total = value[ID == 'Total'],
            ID,
            value,
            Prop = value/Total) %>% 
  filter(ID != 'Total')

#     Total                        ID   value      Prop
# 1 8204988 Black or African American 1336133 0.1628440
# 2 8204988                     White 6283529 0.7658182
```

Comment: That is a much more elegant solution! I never thought about subsetting a vector within the dataframe for the calculation, seems obvious now lol. Thank you for your insight!